# How can I measure text size in a way browsers do?

Tags: internet-explorer, c#-4.0, firefox, gdi+

I'm trying to measure the size of a string in pixels in an standalone application (windows or Java) but the size reported from this app does not match the size of the string reported in FF or IE.

I use the code below to measure the size of the string "Graphics" and it returns 97 pixels. FF and IE report the size of the the string as 64 pixels. The only thing that comes to my mind is that the dpi, but I explicitly set that.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how can I achieve this? As said earlier, I'm looking for a standalone way of measuring text but the results need to be comparable to the sizes reports by browsers.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        SizeF f = new SizeF();
        bmp.SetResolution(CreateGraphics().DpiX, CreateGraphics().DpiY);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            FontFamily ffm = FontFamily.Families.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Name.Equals("Arial"));

            using (System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(ffm, 12.0F,  FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point))
            {
                float ff = font.SizeInPoints;
                f = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g,"Graphics", font, new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue), TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);
            }
        }
```

I am measuring the size in the browser by creating this span tag and getting its size using js.

```
<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt;">Graphics</span>
```

Comment: Which browsers sizes do you want to match?  The ones that use GDI, the ones that use DirectWrite, the ones on Mac, the ones on Linux?  They all report different sizes....  Chances are you're using GDI here; Firefox and recent IE on Windows use DirectWrite.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I get that my question is vague. I wrote up a quick DirectDrite app (win) and the text sizes are comparable to FF! Thanks a lot. Do you know how is text drawn on Linux (any distro)? Since Windows uses DirectWrite, what does linux use?

Comment: I don't know offhand, sorry....